# How does Ken Block's Hoonicorn V2 filter air from the turbos?

Tags: turbocharger, air-intake, air-filter

Ken Block's 1965 Ford Mustang dubbed the "Hoonicorn V2" features a pair of turbos that stick out of the hood. If you look at the picture of the engine bay there appears to be no air filtering mechanism. Is there some kind of air filtration integrated into the intake manifold?

[image]

EDIT:
Follow up question: If there is no actual air filtration, how does a high performance engine like this operate without becoming damaged from the air particles?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Thanks! I love automobiles and the gymkhana films and this question has always bugged me.

Comment: Ken is flippin' awesome with what he can do with a car ... I've watched most of the Gymkhana videos and am *always* amazed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't have a filtering element (for the most part). The only thing kept out are larger chunks as there are coarse screens which are included with the turbo horns.

Comment: I added a follow up question based on this answer: How does a high performance engine like this operate without becoming damaged from the air particles?

Comment: @MplsAmigo the thing about a motor like this is it will likely do a very small amount of miles in its lifetime. As such the extra wear from dirt particles will be negligible over the wear and tear of how this kind of car is driven.  To add having all those nice sponsors who would love to send you a new crate motor definitely helps.

Comment: So in other words, a purpose built engine like this doesn't need the same kind of air filtration as most road going vehicles to operate within its intended lifespan. Thanks guys!

Comment: I’ve known any number of competition engines which haven’t run air filters.  I’ve also known roadcars that run unfiltered.  It’s not ideal if the motor ingests something but it certainly doesn’t stop an engine from working.

Comment: @MplsAmigo - It isn't that it *doesn't need* a filter element, it's that they just choose not to use one. It scares my mechanical self every time I see something like that, but then again I have to remember not to judge what other people do with their engines. I would bet not only do the sponsors have no issues with this, but I'm pretty sure Ken Block and the Hoonigans aren't hurting for money to do this kind of thing. All in a days fun! :o)

Comment: Running without a filter will give maximum performance (at the cost of longevity), to be honest I'd be expecting a ~1400bhp engine running on methanol and being driven as hard as the Gymkhana cars are it'll be needing rebuilds before the ingested particles could become an issue. Expensive certainly but with factory sponsorship from Ford footing the bill it's probably not an issue for them

Comment: Also if you haven't seen it yet there's an excellent "Making of" series called *The Gymkhana Files* on Amazon video that follows them making Gymkhana_ten

Comment: Sweet! Ill have to check that out!